# Linking LAPACK, 64-bit, Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 64-bit, lapack

I'm unable to compile introductory Lapack code in Visual Studio 2013 for a 64-bit platform.  Summary of what I'm trying to do:

- Get Lapack up and running in support of 64-bit C++ software I'm writing in Visual Studio 2013.
- I'm using the same directions given at http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#build by following directions for using the pre-built libraries (*.dll, *.lib & *.h) and referencing those in my build.

Visual Studio steps I'm taking:

- I start a new project - picking the Visual C++ Empty Project template
- In project properties, I first go to Configuration Manager and create a new solution platform of x64 (copying the Win32 settings)
- Then for all configurations and for all platforms I point the Linker Additional Library Dependencies to where I put the prebuilt *.lib files.  I also add to the Linker => Input the libblas.lib and liblapack.lib libraries as instructed.
- Note 1: I'm not adding any of the Lapacke stuff yet since I don't believe the simple example program I'm trying to run will need that stuff (and adding those paths did not seem to help in earlier attempts.)
- Note 2: I know that the libraries I downloaded are 64-bit only - but I applied these project properties to 'all platforms' (meaning including the 32-bit platform) to demonstrate something, below...
- Then in Visual Studio, I added a single C++ source file 'source.cpp' with the code provided at www.cs.rochester.edu/~bh/cs400/using_lapack.html.  Here's the code

> 

```
 #include < stdio.h>

 extern "C" void dgesv_(const int *N, const int *nrhs, double *A, const int *lda, int *ipiv, double *b, const int *ldb, int *info);
 extern "C" void dgels_(const char *trans, const int *M, const int *N, const int *nrhs, double *A, const int *lda, double *b, const int *ldb, double *work,
 const int * lwork, int *info);

int main(void)
{
    double A[9] = { 76, 27, 18, 25, 89, 60, 11, 51, 32 };
    double b[3] = { 10, 7, 43 };

    int N = 3;
    int nrhs = 1;
    int lda = 3;
    int ipiv[3];
    int ldb = 3;
    int info;

    dgesv_(&N, &nrhs, A, &lda, ipiv, b, &ldb, &info);

    if (info == 0) /* succeed */
        printf("The solution is %lf %lf %lf\n", b[0], b[1], b[2]);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "dgesv_ fails %d\n", info);

    return info;
}
```

- And then I try to compile this program (in either Debug or Release configuration) - for an x64 platform and get the error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dgesv_ referenced in function main

which seems to indicate that the prebuilt libraries do not contain these functions.

- The very odd thing is that if I change the platform to 'win32', the project compiles! (huh?)  So it's finding those libraries for the 32-bit platform.  (Btw, if I try to run the executable generated there, I get an error that a *.dll file is missing - which is not surprising given that I only downloaded the 64-bit libraries...)

Also, adding an underscore before dgesv_ in the code also does not seem to work - giving me the error upon compilation:

> fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

which also tracks with some of the discussion at icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=4260

Again, this entire issue seems to track the discussion at http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=4260 and folks there seemed to indicate that building the libraries yourself with CMAKE is a solution (I'm trying that but running into issues there with it not finding the proper fortran compiler in the MinGW-W64 libraries I downloaded <= that's probably appropriate for a different post!).  More importantly, in the last post of that thread, 'admin' indicated that they corrected any previous problem with these pre-built libaries and that they should work now.  So I must be doing something incorrect, right?.  Does anyone see a problem in the workflow I'm using here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked some more on this (and interfaced with some folks on the Lapack discussion forum).  There are two posts there that describe the details:

- The first, at http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=4873&p=11711#p11711, essentially duplicates the question I asked above.  The conclusion from that interface was that the pre-built libraries available at icl.c.utk.edu are out-of-date for my system and I was encouraged to build my own Lapack libraries using CMake.
- The second post, at http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=4875&p=11710#p11710, describes a problem I was having getting CMake to generate these libraries.  I was following the detailed instructions at http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#build but was making a mistake in how I was using CMake.  Bottom line, I needed to specify 'MinGW Makefiles' as my 'generator' in CMake (I was specifying 'visual studio'!).  Once I did that, everything proceeded as described in the original directions and I was able to compile the simple Visual Studio project I described above.